# Best way to re-render v-for when I change my route in vue.js or without reload page manual

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How the best way to re-render v-for in my application when I change/move to another route in vue js?

In my case I use `vuex`, `vuex-persistedstate` and `moment` for save localStorage and show `a moment ago` time.

But how to use rerender v-for without data changes from my `API` and reload page manual?

If you see
[image]

Recent Activity data always cache in `localStorage`. But if **no new data** from api, how to make this always become `3 minutes ago` then `4 minutes ago` etc....

It happend only if I reload the page. Because my code like

```
<template>
<div class="widget">
    <h4 class="widget-title">Recent Activity</h4>
    <ul class="activitiez">
        <li v-for="act in recentActivity" :key="act._id" :id="act._id">
            <div class="activity-meta">
                <i v-html="convertToMoment(act.created_at)"></i>
                <span v-html="act.activity"></span>
                <h6>by <a href="#" v-html="act.sent_name"></a></h6>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import {mapGetters, mapActions} from "vuex"

export default {
    created() {
        this.fetchRecentActivityData()
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters(["recentActivity"])
    },
    methods: {
        ...mapActions(["fetchRecentActivityData"]),
        convertToMoment(data) {
            return moment(data).fromNow()
        }
    },
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

and my store code

```
import axios from 'axios';

const state = {
    recentActivityStore: [],
    errorBag: null,
    timingStore: Date.now()
};

const getters = {
    recentActivity: state => state.recentActivityStore,
    recentActivityTiming: state => state.timingStore
};

const actions = {
    async fetchRecentActivityData({ commit }) {
        const recentAct = this.state.recentactivity.recentActivityStore
        if(_.isEmpty(recentAct)) {
            const response = await axios.get('/recent/activity')
            commit('UPDATE_RECENT_ACTIVITY', response.data)
        }
        commit('UPDATE_TIMING', Date.now())
    }
};

const mutations = {
    UPDATE_RECENT_ACTIVITY: (state, data) => {
        state.recentActivityStore = data
    },
    UPDATE_TIMING: (state, data) => {
        state.timingStore = data
    }
};

export default {
    state,
    getters,
    actions,
    mutations
};
```

How to make my `v-for` reload without refresh page manual? Then `3 minutes ago` then `4 minutes ago` happened

Thanks

Comment: Please don't upload [images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3082296). They can't be copied to create a solution, aren't searchable for future readers and harder to read than text. Please post the actual code **as text** to create a [mcve].

Comment: Sorry @adiga  already changed

Comment: I thought you can register a setInterval to update your data time per minutes.

Comment: what if no data has changed at all? will not trigered changes on the screen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codepen : https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvgxRJ

To solve this create a vue `filter`. Code : [Vuejs time ago filter](https://gist.github.com/dagalti/1f836fd76b53c6872d50f4c95aa3bf84)

```
    filters: {
      timeago: function (pdate, ctime) {
         if (!pdate || !ctime) return ''
         return moment(pdate).from(ctime)
       }
     },
```

apply this filter in HTML

```
        <i>{{act.created_at | timeago(currenttime)}}</i>
```

It calculates the time ago based on current time. Then in setInterval update the currenttime every 50 seconds. It will update the component every 50 seconds.

```
           data:()=>({
             currenttime: Date.now(),
             timer: ''
             }),
     created() {
        this.fetchRecentActivityData()
        this.timer = setInterval(() => {this.currenttime = Date.now()}, 50000);
    }
```

Final Code.

```
   export default {
         data:()=>({
         currenttime: Date.now(),
         timer: ''
         }),
         filters: {
          timeago: function (pdate, ctime) {
             if (!pdate || !ctime) return ''
             return moment(pdate).from(ctime)
           }
         },
        created() {
            this.fetchRecentActivityData()
            this.timer = setInterval(() => {this.currenttime = Date.now()}, 50000);
        },
        beforeDestroy() {
            clearInterval(this.timer)
        },
        computed: {
            ...mapGetters(["recentActivity"])
        },
        methods: {
            ...mapActions(["fetchRecentActivityData"]),
        },
    }
```

in HTML

```
   <li v-for="act in recentActivity" :key="act._id" :id="act._id">
        <div class="activity-meta">
            <i>{{act.created_at | timeago(currenttime)}}</i>
            <span v-html="act.activity"></span>
            <h6>by <a href="#" v-html="act.sent_name"></a></h6>
        </div>
    </li>
```